# PHP, preg_match and double quotes

Tags: php, preg-match

I am a complete noob here.  I am trying to extract Marine Corp. (without quotes from $data.  I've searched and searched for how to deal with double quotes but am coming up short.  Can someone please offer some guidance?  Thank you.

```
$data = '"title":{"rendered":"Marine Corp."}';
preg_match('/title":{"rendered":"(.*)"}/U',$data,$matches);
echo $matches[0]; //=> target
```

Comment: Is that the complete data you're dealing with? Or do you possible actually have a nice [***JSON object***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
<?php
//If it is valid json then try with json_decode()
$json_string = '{"title":{"rendered":"Marine Corp."}}';
$json_array = json_decode($json_string,1);
echo "For Json Object:\n" . $json_array['title']['rendered']."\n";

//If it is just string pattern then with preg_match()
$re = '/"title":{"rendered":"(.*?)\.?"}/';
$str = '"title":{"rendered":"Marine Corp."}
"title":{"rendered":"Marine Police"}';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
echo "\nFor String: \n";
foreach($matches as $match){
    echo $match[1]."\n";
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
For Json Object:
Marine Corp.

For String: 
Marine Corp
Marine Police
```

See PHP demo : https://eval.in/973297

See REGEX demo : https://regex101.com/r/GyGN9U/1

Comment: The example $data I was showing was part of a much larger string which was not well formed json.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're after is `/\"title\"\:\{\"rendered\"\:\"(.*)\"\}/`

```
$data = '"title":{"rendered":"Marine Corp."}';
preg_match('/\"title\"\:\{\"rendered\"\:\"(.*)\"\}/',$data,$matches);
$tmp = array_shift( $matches );
```

`$tmp` will hold "`Marine Corp.`"

On another note it seems like you have a JSON object there. If that's the case you could do, which would be a lot simpler:

```
$data = '{"title":{"rendered":"Marine Corp."}}';
$tmp = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($tmp['title']['rendered']);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you won't to extract "Marine Corp" from the $data string use the str_replace()
function:

echo str_replace('Marine Corp.', '', $data);

result: "title":{"rendered":""}